# Is there any way to generate dynamic web form from XSD?

Tags: html, xml, xsd

Actually i have no idea how to generate web form from xsd.  If you can help then it's good for me.

Comment: Please completed the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of projects to build software that would read a schema and generate one or more forms from it, often but not always using XForms.  All the ones I have heard about succeeded for at least some XSD schemas, and produced forms which either were satisfactory for the intended use or could be modified further by hand to make them better.  I don't believe any of them created absolutely beautiful forms for every imaginable schema, which is perhaps why there has been more than one such project.

So the short answer to the question asked is:  yes, there is.  You can find out more about it by spending a few hours searching the Web and reading about the projects you find.